My emulator is not showing up as an option in android studio devices
My physical device and emulator both are not showing in connected device option in both vs code as well as in android studio even after enabling usb debugging and creating emulator via virtual device manager still vs code and android studio are not able to detect my device ??
I deleted the emulator and again created a new one then also it was not detected same I did with the physical device by enabling and disabling the usb debugging..

did adb devices see your device ?
some android device you have to set usb mode(when plug usb) to android auto/File transfer to debug with your device
